# Start page numbering after Table of Contents in wicked_pdf

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am generating a pdf from html using wicked_pdf in a RoR app.
The wicked_pdf documentation shows [how to number all pages](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#page-numbering), but

1. I want to start numbering pages from the page after the Table of Contents page.
2. The page numbers linked to the listed sections in the ToC should also start with 1, instead of 2/3 as they are starting now ( taking the cover page as 1, and ToC page as 2).

How can one do that?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?